# Pegar valor de atributo DOM PHP

Tags: php, html, libcurl, dom, parse

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação para pegar certos valores de uma página e inseri-los em uma página minha. Não sei programar, mas mesmo assim estou me arriscando, pois é para melhoria da minha função(analista de licitações).
Até agora consegui pegar um dos dados, porém os outros dois não estou conseguindo pegar.
Estou usando `CURL` para pegar os dados da sessão, e `Dom` para pegar os valores que preciso. Segue meu código até agora:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);


// iniciar sessao
$ch = curl_init();
// opcoes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, ');

//executar sessao
$output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
       echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
//fechar sessao
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($output);
// Consultando atributo onclick
$codsprg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($codsprg as $codprg) {
$onclick[] = $codprg->getAttribute('onclick');
}
$origens  = array('Motivo_Suspensao(', ');', 'Dados_Pregao(');
$destinos = array('', '', '');
$nova = str_replace($origens, $destinos, $onclick);
$nova = array_filter($nova);
$nova = array_unique($nova);
$nova = array_slice($nova, 0);

// resultado
echo '<pre>';
//print_r ($nova);  Até aqui funciona

$numsprg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($numsprg as $numprg) {
$num[] = $numprg->getAttribute('onclick');
}
$new = $num;
echo $new;
?>
```

Código que eu quero pegar: Preciso pegar os dados do pregão, que está entre parenteses (esse já consegui), o número do pregão que está na mesma linha do dados do pregão(ex: 512016) e a `uasg` que esta na linha debaixo(ex: 155023).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira parte do código faço a conexão com o `CURL`, depois uso o `DOM` para pegar o primeiro dado que preciso(dados_pregao). Depois disso já testei várias combinações possíveis com o DOM e sempre retornam erros como:

> ```
> Trying to get property of non-object e 
> Call to undefined method DOMDocument::find() in
> ```

Já pesquisei aqui no SOpt e testei todas as soluções possíveis, sem sucesso.
O erro atual é:

```
Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\aclicita\teste.php on line 49
```

A linha 49 é:

```
echo $new;
```

Comment: Seria melhor dizer com mais especificidade quais os erros e quais as linhas. Sobre o "Não sei programar, mas mesmo assim estou me arriscando", não é tanto um problema, pois grande parte das coisas com PHP aqui se encaixam perfeitamente nesse perfil (mesmo que o autor "jure que é programador"). Se conseguir [edit] a questão e dividir seu problema em problemas menores, ou detalhar os erros, ajuda. Uma boa pergunta independe da sua habilidade atual em programar. Aqui tem umas dicas: [Ask], [Help].

Comment: @Inkeliz, os dados que preciso estão na imagem anexa. Dados_Pregao(XXXXXX) = preciso pegar os numeros entre parenteses (Até aqui eu consegui. Na mesma linha tem o retorno que é 512016 (esse dado eu preciso). E na linha logo abaixo tem 155023 (esse é o outro dado que preciso). O restante eu não preciso.

Comment: @Bacco, vou informar o erro como está o código agora.

Comment: Pra que os colchetes no num?

Comment: Coloquei para uma melhor visualização com o print_r, para numerar a saída para que eu possa usar posteriormente, tipo: [0], [1], ... Seu eu estiver errado me corrija, por favor.

Comment: nesse caso não use echo para mostrar, use print_r

Comment: Falha minha, Obrigado. Porém vejamos, segue a imagem com este código consigo pegar os dados_pregao, que eu já havia conseguido, agora preciso dos outros dois valores.

Comment: Boa noite, acessei manualmente a URL "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp" do CURL e mostra uma mensagem de acesso negado redirecionando para https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/accessdenied.htm

Comment: Essa página só é acessível após o login no navegador.

Comment: Ainda usando o curl, primeiro você precisa logar!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, depois de um tempo dando uma olhada no dom e suas funções, consegui fazer meu código funcionar. Segue abaixo código que está funcionando.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

//Converte caracteres acentuados para não acentuado
$conversao = array('á' => 'a','à' => 'a','ã' => 'a','â' => 'a', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'í' => 'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', "ö"=>"o", 'ú' => 'u', 'ü' => 'u', 'ç' => 'c', 'ñ'=>'n', 'Á' => 'A', 'À' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Í' => 'I', 'Ï'=>'I', "Ö"=>"O", 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ç' =>'C', 'Ñ'=>'N');

// iniciar sessao
$ch = curl_init();
// opcoes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ASPSESSIONIDSCRRTCSB=LPDMGOACKEJMOBEAJNBNELNC; ASPSESSIONIDQCQRRBQC=ENJMGOACPDMCKBMILFDFHMNJ');

//executar sessao
$output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
       echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
$output = strtr($output, $conversao); // função de conversão acentuado/não acentuado
//fechar sessao
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($output);
// Pega os códigos de cada pregão
$codsprg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($codsprg as $codprg) {
$onclick[] = $codprg->getAttribute('onclick');
}
$origens  = array('Motivo_Suspensao(', ');', 'Dados_Pregao(');
$destinos = array('', '', '');
$nova = str_replace($origens, $destinos, $onclick);  // remove palavras indejadas
$nova = array_filter($nova);
$nova = array_unique($nova);
$nova = array_slice($nova, 0);

// resultado
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r ($nova);

// Pegar os valores do número do pregão
$numsprg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($numsprg as $item) {
$prg[] = $item->nodeValue . "\n";
$prg = array_map('trim', $prg); // remove os espaços em branco
}
$origensprg  = array('Suspensao', 'Administrativa', 'Acompanhar', ' ');
$destinosprg = array('', '', '', '');
$newprg = str_replace($origensprg, $destinosprg, $prg); // remove palavras indejadas
$newprg = array_filter($newprg);
$newprg = array_slice($newprg, 0);
// print_r ($newprg);

//Pega os valores da uasg
$numsuasg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($numsuasg as $numuasg) {
$uasg[] = $numuasg->nodeValue . "\n";
$uasg = array_map('trim', $uasg); // remove os espaços em branco
}
$newuasg = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $uasg);   // remove caracteres não numericos do output
$newuasg = array_filter($newuasg);
$newuasg = array_slice($newuasg, 2);
//print_r($newuasg);
?>
```